# Is it possible to access a Gmail account with 2FA enabled from another Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have two Gmail accounts, A and B.

Account A is my primary inbox.

Up until now, I have been using POP to access the contents of Account B, and using the "Send email as" functionality to send emails from it.

However, I recently added 2FA to Account B, and now every time I try to use it with POP and SMTP it says "Password not accepted" or words to that effect.

My understanding is that "App Passwords" should be the solution, but when I try to enter them as the password, it says "Web login required".

Is there a way around this?

Comment: As this question is specifically about the use of Gmail in a desktop application, it should meet the topic requirements for SuperUser.

Comment: Hi @Margaret. This would prbably be better posted in [WebApplications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) as likely to be closed as [off topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here

Answer (score 1):

You may have to turn on "Less secure app access" for account B at this link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps